# Rivals to the FIDE

Tags: fide, kasparov, karpov

Though the [PCA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professional_Chess_Association) and the Classical Chess Championship have failed, the wish to reform, dethrone or replace the FIDE [evidently remains strong,](http://chess.co.uk/twic/chessnews/events/staunton-memorial-dinner-2010/karpov-kasparov-press-conference-8-september-2010) at least in some quarters of the chess world.  [Some suggest](http://www.chessbase.com/newsdetail.asp?newsid=6710) that the present FIDE leadership remains entrenched with little authentic support.  I lack personal knowledge of the matter, but the press one reads does seem pretty one-sided, does it not?  The press seems implicitly to concur in the *premise* (never mind the finding) that the FIDE were crooked.  The FIDE's present regime could be excellent for all I know but, if a credible defense of it exists, the defense does not seem to be appearing in any language I can read, nor am I aware of it.

If this is correct, then conditions would *seem* to be ripe for the rise of a new organization to contest the FIDE's authority.  However, I know of none such.  Is there such a new organization?  Is any serious effort in planning or underway to reform, dethrone or replace the FIDE?

> To be clear, I am not asking whether the FIDE is a good organization or a bad one, but rather whether and in what way a credible alternative does or soon might exist.

Comment: I think it is better to close this question as it can easily turn into a debate.

Comment: I sympathize with the view of @Akavall, especially since the text of the question openly encourages editorializing from others for some reason that I don't understand, and so it's already received one "non-answer answer." On the other hand, I do think there is at least one plausible answer to the factual question that is asked (whether an alternative to FIDE does or might soon exist). So I won't close the question now, but I am going to edit out the invitation to editorialize.

Comment: Then I will vote for close.

Comment: @EdDean, I see your point. I think you answered the question very well.

Comment: @EdDean:  That's right.  Thanks for the edit.

Comment: I do not care for FIDE but there is no alternative going to happen.  You can play USCF in the USA and not miss FIDE's existence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One body which isn't exactly an alternative to FIDE now, but could perhaps become so down the road depending on how the future plays out, is the [Association of Chess Professionals](http://www.chessprofessionals.org/) (not to be confused with Kasparov's Professional Chess Association, mentioned in the question). It is basically a global union for any folks working in chess - players, organizers, journalists, and so on - rather than some sort of governing body like FIDE. So in this sense it is in no way a competitor to FIDE; nevertheless, it can act as something of a counterweight to FIDE, much as players' unions in other sports keep their governing bodies in check (e.g. the [MLBPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major_League_Baseball_Players_Association) and Major League Baseball).

The ACP has grown in stature, at least somewhat, since its initial inception in 2003. Former ACP president GM Joel Lautier [said the following in 2005](http://www.chess-players.org/eng/news/viewarticle.html?id=293),

> Some time ago it seemed that such collaboration [between ACP and FIDE] could indeed be possible, but at present FIDE avoids any contact with us, does not respond to our mails, and we don't expect any positive changes of the situation.

Contrast this with FIDE [recently giving the ACP a seat at the table](http://www.chessvibes.com/reports/acp-and-fide-agree-on-close-cooperation), agreeing to make them a part of FIDE's decision-making process. Whether or not such an agreement actually means very much I certainly don't know. But it does demonstrate that FIDE now considers the ACP to be a body to reckon with, which implies that the ACP is gaining enough heft to potentially be an agent for change where FIDE is concerned, either from within or without.